# input type date html5 and receiving data from databse

Tags: php, html, date, input

I'm working on `Chrome` locally with `WAMP`, `PHP` version 5. I use an input type date, which displays a calendar. In fact I get some variables within the data editing page of my users. The concern I have is that all the data are collected. However for date, instead of displaying the record in the database (confirmed by `var_dump`) he displays a placeholder `Day / Month / Year`

which does not interest me, I want this placeholder if and only if my field is empty.

Here is the syntax of the field:

```
<input name="datedepart" type="date"  value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data["congestart"])) ?>"/>
```

Is there a way for that?

Receive dear All my utmost respect.

Comment: The RFC says that the value attribute needs the date in format YYYY-MM-DD, for example 1996-12-19. Try date('Y-m-d', strtotime...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it will probably be enough to change the date format to ISO, like 2012-08-22:

```
<input name="datedepart" type="date"
value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data["congestart"])) ?>"/>
```

If your server expects some other format, you will have to convert it using Javascript (ISO is the standard used in HTML5 specification, so the value of the input field will always be ISO, no matter how Chrome displays it).

**update, clarification:**

Date field can only contain a valid date. When you try to set it it to some random garbage, then the value becomes empty. When the value is empty - Chrome displays the placeholder. The only valid format for dates in HTML5 is ISO: 2012-03-04. Just try and see:

```
<input value='2004-02-12' type='date'>
```

Comment: we use the local format d-m-Y the fact is that nothing is display just the default placeholder wich is Jours/Mois/Année

Comment: but can you tell me why chrome just display the placeholder not the value? morover there is no place holder chrome put its own placeholder

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: Date field can only contain a valid date. When you try to set it it to some random garbage, then the value becomes empty. When the value is empty - Chrome displays the placeholder. The only valid format for dates in HTML5 is ISO: 2012-03-04. Just try: <input value='2004-02-12' type='date'>. If your code does not work, it is probably a problem somewhere else [I update my answer].

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: it does not matter what you use in your database and it does not matter what Chrome displays (the display can differ from machine to machine, it is locale dependent). If you want to provide the value, you MUST use Y-m-d. When you read the value, it will be Y-m-d. Perhaps you will need to convert it, either server-side or with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
placeholder="<?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data["congestart"])) ?>"
```

instead of putting it in value.

If this doesn't solve the answer, Then explain a little more about what you want to do?

Comment: thanks for the help it does not work in fact, It always show the default placeholder Jours/Mois/Année

Comment: I've check this the thing is that the value of my input does exist in the value because it comes from the database. It is not display and when I save it to database it turns to 1970/01/01

Answer (score 0):

This works very well from **fdreger**:

```
<input name="datedepart" type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-   d',strtotime($data["congestart"])) ?>"/>
```

I needed the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old thread but i think this can be helpful for someone

Try to use min and max then this will pick your provided value.

Like

```
<input type="date" min="2014-09-08" max="2018-09-08" value="2015-02-24" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me

```
<input class="form-control calendar" name="datedepart" required="" type="date" id="datedepart" aria-required="true" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data["congestart"])) ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to remove quotes around the value returned from php, so in the case of your code it would try this:

```
<input name="datedepart" type="date"  value=<?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data["congestart"])) ?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
    <input name="datedepart" type="date" value=<?php echo strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($data['congestart'])); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="forms-sample" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Program/program_general">
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="View">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ProgramID']; ?>" name="program_id">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ProgramName']; ?>" name="program_name">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ProgramDescription']; ?>" name="program_description">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['ProgramStartDate'])); ?>" name="program_startdate">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['ProgramEndDate'])); ?>" name="program_enddate">
    </td>
</form>


<input name="program_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername1" value="<?php if (!empty($this
    ->input
    ->post('program_name')))
{
    echo $this
        ->input
        ->post('program_name');
} ?>" placeholder="Program Name">
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.